# Storing the current date time as a string variable

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I'm trying to store the current time into a string variable upon the click of a finalisation button, that I can then pass through a method giving it an end date.

I thought it could work using this code:

```
string endDate = null;
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(endDate, "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
dt.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

However I am getting this error when the program is run and the code is debugged.

> String reference not set to an instance of a String. Parameter name: s

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `string endDate = "30102012";`

Comment: You're trying to parse `null`, and you get a null argument exception.  What's confusing about that?  Pass in a non-null value to `DateTime.ParseExact`...

Answer (score 4):

EDIT:
As pointed out in the comments you are also passing a null value for endDate into the ParseExact() method. I'm confused at what you are trying to accomplish here. If you simply want to get a string value for the current DateTime when you click your button all you need to do is:

```
string currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

There is no need for parsing a string at all unless I'm missing what you are trying to do.

You aren't assigning the value of your dt.ToString() call to a variable. Try using

```
endDate = dt.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Comment: Why not? It is certainly not getting assigned anywhere which is at the very least the first step in solving the problem he's having.

Comment: I'm *not* saying your answer isn't helpful. But because execution terminates before the `ToString` call, the real problem is that the first argument of `DateTime.ParseExact` cannot be `null`, as Servy pointed out in a comment on the question.

Comment: @codesparkle Thanks I only briefly glanced at this and didn't even notice that. Edited my answer to be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`dt.ToString("yyyyMMdd");` returns a string. You need to assign it to a string variable. It doesn't change dt into a string.

I think what you wanted was:

```
endDate = dt.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```